# My Microsoft account won’t connect to my Minecraft on PS4

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ps4

My friend on ps4 Bought Minecraft and was only able to play once, after he closed app for the night, he tried launching it again the next day, and immediately it said sign in failed. He claims to have done everything to fix this problem, even call Microsoft, Mojang, and Sony.

Comment: What did Microsoft, Mojang, and Sony tell your friend?

Answer (score 1):

Your friend may have downloaded the demo version of Minecraft for PS4. This version only allows you to play it for one day.

Alternatively, if he has it via PS Plus, he may need to check his subscription as it may have expired.

Comment: Hi @gangster - welcome to the site! I've combined your separate answers into one for you.